popup menu "No context-sensitive help installed"
I created a VCL program with a popup menu and a button:
Button1.PopupMenu := PopupMenu1;
PopupMenu1.HelpContext := 0;

Today I tried to press F1 when my mouse moved to MenuItems and it said:

No context-sensitive help installed

I found that HelpContext = 0 means: no help. But why? This is Delphi 2010. With Delphi 10.3 the same.

If you want to suppress this message, you can drop a TApplicationEvents on your main form and add an event handler for OnException that checks for EHelpSystemException.


I found that HelpContext = 0 means: no help. But why?

Because a help context ID can't be 0, that means no ID is assigned. The default HelpContext value is 0, and the DFM skips storing ID 0. This is just the way the VCL works.
If you want Help to appear for your menu, then you need a non-zero context ID assigned to either the menu itself or one of its items.

Enabling help in Delphi applications require a lot more than just Setting the non-zeroHelpContext value. First you need to add Vcl.HtmlHelpViewer unit into uses clause in the project file. Initialization section of the mentioned unit installs and registers the appropriate context-sensitive help viewer. Skipping this is causing the error message that OP is mentioning to show.  Then you need to provide your application with a path to the help file. ...

...  You do this using TApplication.HelpFile property or using forms HelpFile property if you want specific form to use different help file than the application's default help file. Only then can you go setting up different HelpContext values. Any way Embarcadero has a whole section in their documentation on Enabling Help in Applications

@SilverWarior those comments should be posted as a separate answer on its own.
